# How to bulk upload in the Azure storage Blob

Tags: c#

I have successfully done with single file uploading in Azure using C#. 
I have also tried for bulk uploading but failed to find any method which directly supports C#.
Is there any direct method is present for bulk uploading in C# on Azure

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386073/fastest-way-to-bulk-upload-files-into-azure-c

Comment: Please can you include your code for single file upload and the code that you have tried with the error messages you got.